# Does Keras module have a method that prints a list of only activation functions?

Tags: keras

Here's the code snippet I used to print an activation function list, but it also prints deserialize, get, and serialize methods that are not activation functions

```
for act in dir(keras.activations):
    if not act.startswith('_'):
        print(act)
```

It looks like there are no such methods as far as my research goes. Does Keras module have a method that prints a list of only activation functions?